# Issues appending a character to an empty string in C

Tags: c, append, cs50

So I'm trying to make code that appends a character to an empty string in order to build an encrypted string from an input given by the user, but when I try to use the function `strcat()` I get the "segmentation fault" error. I've tried defining a pointer (*cipher = "") but I still get a segmentation error. I also tried defining cipher as an empty array (cipher[] = "";) but I still get the same error. any tips?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  string key = argv[1];

  if (strlen(key) == 0)
  {
    printf("Please input a key");
    return 1;
  } else
  if (strlen(key) != 26)
  {
    printf("Please input a 26 character key");
    return 1;
  } else
  {
    string  plainText = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int n = strlen(plainText);
    char *cipher = "";
    for (int i = 0; i< strlen(plainText); i++)
    {
      char letter = plainText[i];
      int ASCII = (int) plainText[i];
      char translation;

      if (ASCII > 96 && ASCII < 123) {
        int position = ASCII - 97;
        int keyASCII = (int) key[position];
        int  toLowerCase = keyASCII + 32;
        translation = (char) toLowerCase;
      } else
      if (ASCII > 64 && ASCII < 91) {
        int position = ASCII - 65;
        translation = key[position];
      } else {
        translation = letter;
      }
      strcat(cipher, &translation);
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s", cipher);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `char *cipher = "";` That just makes a pointer to a string literal which is not writable. You need to have a writable buffer. Something like: `char cipher[n+1] = "";`. Assuming your compiler supports variable length arrays. Otherwise use `malloc` to allocate the memory.

Comment: All this `int ASCII = (int) plainText[i];` is nonsense, you can just use `letter` in its place everywhere. Also why are you both using `strlen` to get the `n` but also to limit the loop? Also the return value of `strlen` is of type `size_t`; an unsigned integer type that you should use for `i` as well...

Comment: You cannot use `strcat` with a pointer to a single character either. The 2nd argument to `strcat` must point to a properly null-terminated string.